# How to get selected child node values in a angular mat tree

Tags: angular, tree, mat

In angular 14 mat tree, have structure like parent --> child --> sub child . If I select **child** check box then it select all **sub child** elements.  here I want only sub child selected values when I click on submit button.

here is the stack Blitz example I tried.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-multi-select-tree-demo-nymntq?file=app%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.html,app%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.ts

here when I click on submit, it's returning all selected dependents I want only sub child selected check values.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If hierarchy is upto 3 level & you want to get sub-child only, You Can easily get it with customizing your filter method in submit function.

`.filter((descendant) => descendant.isSelected && descendant['children'] === undefined)`

[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-multi-select-tree-demo-x3wtg1?file=app/tree-nested-overview-example.ts)

Comment: thanks for your answer. can we do drag and drop the  sub child with in particular parent by using above sample code.